# php matching array names to another array's values

Tags: php, arrays, match

I have some data that is available to me in arrays.  I have to display the data in rows and columns, like a table.
The first array, $header, looks like this:

```
$header[0]=a, $header[1]=d, $header[2]=b, $header[3]=c, $header[4]=e
```

This array can have any number of elements.  The subsequent arrays represent the rows of my table. They come to me looking like this, and there can be any number of rows:

```
$b[0]=3,$c[0]=4,$a[0]=1,$d[0]=2,$e[0]=5  (in random order)
$c[1]=4,$e[1]=5,$a[1]=1,$b[1]=3,$d[1]=2  (in random order)
$a[2]=5,$b[2]=15,$c[2]=20,$e[2]=25  (in random order and missing an element) 
$a[3]=10,$b[3]=30,$c[3]=40,$bananas[3]=25 (random, missing and extra)
$c[4]=4,$e[4]=5,$c[4]=1,$b[4]=3,$d[4]=2,$a[4]=1 (random and duplicate)
```

I want to determine the name of the arrays in each of the rows, and reorder them so that they appear in the columns according to the values in the header array, so that the header array value matches the row array name, and the row array value is placed in the correct column.  To illustrate, the data above would yield this:

```
a,d,b,c,e 
1,2,3,4,5 
1,2,3,4,5 
5,,15,20,25 
10,,30,40, 
1,2,3,5,5
```

The rules:

- header - in the order determined by the index
- random - reordered to match header order
- missing - to show blank or null value in that column
- extra - to be ignored
- duplicate - if numeric, add, if alpha then concatenate with a ~

Another example:

```
$header[0]=apple, $header[1]=banana, $header[3]=grape, $header4=fruit
$banana[0]=yellow, $grape[0]=purple, $apple[0]=red, $fruit[0]=fresh
$grape[1]=cluster, $fruit[1]=bag, $apple[1]=bushel, $banana[1]=bunch
$grape[2]=cluster, $fruit[2]=bag, $banana[2]=bunch, $fruit[2]=crunchy, $extra[2]=new
```

would yield

```
apple, banana, grape, fruit
red, yellow, purple, fresh
bushel, bunch, cluster, bag
, bunch, cluster, bag~crunchy
```

I'd post some code, but I don't have a clue about how to begin

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: Doesn't make much sense.  Maybe a `var_export()` of your arrays.

Comment: If that's how your arrays really are .... it seems really strange to begin with.

Comment: Yeah, they really are.. they are transposed, in multi-dimensional sort of way.. maybe that suggests an approach.  I'm really stumped.

Comment: Jay, thank you.  What have I tried? Nothing...My problem? I'm clueless as to how to approach this.  I'm looking for an approach here.

Comment: what is your data source?

Comment: Hi, just saw this.  Include file.  I think he's generating the file without testing the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is it mostly working, the part I don't understand is how you determine the duplicate, as when you set `$fruit[2]='bag';` and then set `$fruit[2]='crunchy';` it will actually be overwritten so it will be as if `$fruit[2]='bag';` was never executed to begin with

> sample code

```
$header[0]= 'apple'; $header[1]='banana'; $header[3]='grape'; $header[4]='fruit';
$banana[0]='yellow'; $grape[0]='purple'; $apple[0]='red'; $fruit[0]='fresh';
$grape[1]='cluster'; $fruit[1]='bag'; $apple[1]='bushel'; $banana[1]='bunch';
$grape[2]='cluster'; $fruit[2]='bag'; $banana[2]='bunch'; $fruit[2]='crunchy'; $extra[2]='new';

$rows = [];

$maxRows = 0;
$headerSize = sizeOf($header);

$z = 0;
foreach($header as $index => $name) {
    $rows[0][] = $name;
    if (isset($$name)) {
        $x = 0;
        foreach($$name as $index2 => $name2) {
            ++$x;
            if (false === isset($rows[$x])) {
                for($y = 0; $y < $headerSize; $y++) {
                    $rows[$x][$y] = null;
                }
            }
            if (isset($rows[$x][$z])) {
                $rows[$x][$z] .= '~' . $name2;
            } else {
                $rows[$x][$z] = $name2;
            }
        }
    }
    $z++;
}

foreach($rows as $row) {
    echo implode(', ', $row) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

> output

```
apple, banana, grape, fruit
red, yellow, purple, fresh
bushel, bunch, cluster, bag
, bunch, cluster, crunchy
```

Comment: Wow! That's clever. First, to answer your question... you make a good point about overwriting the value.  I guess I missed that because I've only looked at what's going to come in, I haven't actually coded anything or run a script, so that escaped me.  Good catch!  I'll study this further and comment after.  I do notice on the last line, the line should start with a comma, to indicate that the apple column doesn't have a value. Is there a way to add something, like null or ' ' where that element doesn't exist, so that the implode will place that comma there?

Comment: sure, I updated my example, I also dealt with the duplicate too but it does nothing since the value does get overwritten.

Comment: Outstanding! I had to make a couple of edits because of my PHP v. 5.2.17, but it runs like a charm.  Now I'll try it on the real data, and I'll tell my user he's got to clean up his duplicates and deal with them himself.  I'm a newbie, so I can't vote up, but I would if I could.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Hi Augwa - I ran across some small difficulty.  It looks like there are certain circumstances that can cause the code to behave poorly.  I noticed it with the real data, and the cause looks like when the value of two consecutive header value named arrays (like banana and grape) are both null in a row.

Comment: I have modified code with comments and observations... hopefully, my changes will get moderated in soon.  If not, I'll post them here.

Comment: ok, I guess that's not how you do it... add this data, and the result go bad.  I'll work on it tomorrow, see if I can post a fix.

Two new rows of data:

$fruit[3]='bag'; $fruit[3]='crunchy'; $extra[3]='new';

$fruit[4]='crunchy';$apple[4]='bushel';